# What is Render in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, render

I find the answer is Render in magento 2 but no proper answer not find, so please send any link or answer for clarification this topic.
thanks in advance if you give me the answer

Answer (score 0):

I found some of these links quite good. You can check these :

https://meetanshi.com/blog/use-grid-renderer-in-magento-2/

https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-image-rendering.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html#step-1-create-controller